# How to express "don't care" value for a function/method argument in a test

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I am preparing unit test cases, in which I am invoking methods with one or more arguments. For the purposes of a test case, exact values of certain arguments may not be important, as long as they are from an acceptable input range, or its sub-range (e.g. non-zero).

I want future readers of my test cases to understand my intent. I do not want them to spend time on figuring out why a certain value was used.

Has anyone established a solution to this? Do any testing frameworks provide abstractions for "don't care" values? Are there widespread coding conventions or techniques for that?

I am mostly interested in C, C++, and Python, but I believe that the question applies to many programming languages, and technologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [telling variable names](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/11/30/name-by-role).

- If you have a valid number, you could call the variable `aValidNumber` or `validNumber`.
- If it's any string, you could call the variable `anyString`.
- If the value is, on the other hand, an *invalid* phone number, then use `invalidPhoneNumber`, or `anInvalidPhoneNumber`.

The book *xUnit Test Patterns* also suggests the name *dummy* to indicate a value that's only present to satisfy a compiler or interpreter.

You can also use [Test Data Builders](http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000714.html) to make it clear to readers which values are important, and which ones aren't.

Property-based frameworks such as [QuickCheck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck) (there are ports to many languages) typically take this further and use an abstraction called `Arbitrary`, where an `Arbitrary` instance is, as the name implies, an arbitrary, randomly generated value.

Comment: I am currently slowly treading through the "xUnit Test Patterns" book, sharing its pearls with my team. Your answer confirms my feeling of having test data builders in our testing framework. Currently I use `random()` to initialize such values, a variant of PRNG that generates deterministic numbers. But I understand now I need to wrap it into higher level functions describing the intent of produced values. `ArbitraryXYZ` seems like a good metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

"As long as they are from an acceptable input range" is not the same "don't care".

If a parameter value needs to be valid, but the actual value does not matter for the test case, I usually define the value as a constant or variable named as such, that it is clear to the reader that the value does not matter for the case. Example: `A_VALID_USER_NAME`, which communicates that the test case is about calling the function/method with a valid user name.